# How to derement using has_many :through Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, has-many-through

I'm pretty new to Ruby and having some trouble with how I would approach decrementing info in a db using a has_many :through table. My tables are food_product, menu_item and sale what I'm wanting to have happen is that you can click on a sell this item for the menu_item and have it decrement the amount of orders in the food_product database. Here's the code that I have currently:

FoodProduct model

```
class FoodProduct < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sales
  has_many :menu_items, :through => :sales
  
  validates :food_, presence: true
  validates :amount_ordered_, presence: true
  validates :amount_to_sell_, presence: true
  validates :amount_of_pans_, presence: true
  validates :date_ordered_, presence: true
  validates :date_order_arrives_, presence: true
  validates :soft_out_date_, presence: true
  validates :hard_out_date_, presence: true
end
```

menu_item model

```
class MenuItem < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sales
  has_many :food_products, :through => :sales

end
```

sale model

```
class Sale < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :food_product
  belongs_to :menu_item
end
```

and my schema

```
 create_table "food_products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "food_"
    t.integer "amount_ordered_"
    t.integer "amount_to_sell_"
    t.integer "amount_of_pans_"
    t.integer "orders_per_pan_"
    t.datetime "date_ordered_"
    t.datetime "date_order_arrives_"
    t.datetime "soft_out_date_"
    t.datetime "hard_out_date_"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "menu_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name_"
    t.string "food_item1_"
    t.string "food_item2_"
    t.string "food_item3_"
  end

  create_table "sales", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "food_product_id"
    t.bigint "menu_item_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["food_product_id"], name: "index_sales_on_food_product_id"
    t.index ["menu_item_id"], name: "index_sales_on_menu_item_id"
  end
```

If there's anything else I need to share let me know, I'm not sure of what all info is needed by y'all to help me

Answer (score 0):

I think so you should add `after_create` callback in Sale class.Like this

```
class Sale < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :food_product
  belongs_to :menu_item

  after_create :decrement_order

  def decrement_order
    self.food_product.update_attribute("amount_ordered_", (food_product.amount_ordered_ - 1))
  end
end
```